# How to add country in Magento2?

Tags: configuration, magento2, country

We have Magento version 2.2.5.

We try to enable (add) Kosovo.

So:

1. add in DB directory_country XK, XK and XKX
2. go in /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data and
   edit en.xml/it.xml with Kosovo (already exist) also add Kosovo
3. flush cache with console

When we go to admin configuration to general to add available country not exist. We try also to add a test country and not working. We also try to edit /vendor/magento/module-directory/etc/config.xml add allow country.

How we can do?

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to add new country in Magento just follow the steps given below and you are done with it.

```
Step1: Open lib/zend/locale/data/en.xml

Step2: Locate territories tag in this file

Step3: copy one of the territory tags for the syntax and paste it within the territories tag

Step4: hard part here is to add country code in this file as might not be able to find a unique one, so it’s upto you.

Step5: Save this file

Step6: Open table name directory_country

Step7: It has predefined syntax follow then same and create a new row and enter the same country code as entered in the en.xml file in 3 columns

Step8: Refresh the site’s cache.

Step9: Admin > Configuration > General
```

this new country should be selected in list of allowed countries.

Comment: Not working for my version there is /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data and not /lib/zend/locale/data/

Comment: after that have you clear cache and regenerate static content

Comment: Nothing we regenerate static content, clear cache, flush cache, reindex...

Comment: This worked for version 2.2*, and as PUno pointed out, the directory is /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data, but remember if you use this method, if you update Magento you'll need to reapply the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below link and it helps me to add a new country

[Add new nation into nation's list in Magento 2.3.5](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/330838/add-new-nation-into-nations-list-in-magento-2-3-5/330897#330897)